# How to assign colors to each value in scatter function - GNU Octave

Tags: octave, scatter-plot

How can I use the `scatter` function in GNU Octave in order to assign colors to each plotted value ?

Comment: Do you want exactly 1 color to each vector or it can be repeatable?

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný, what I meant in my question is exactly one color for each vector. I have edited my question to better clarify this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change colormap and 4th parameter of octave's scatter. The parameter is vector 1xn indexing colormap. You can have maximally 255^3 vectors. And how to do that?

### Example solution:

1. Set colormap (matrix 3 x n), which will contain each color exactly ones
2. Use as 4th parameter vector, which is containing each number exactly ones, and has same size like x and y

---

```
clf;
x = randn (100, 1);
y = randn (100, 1);
cmap=[];
for R = 1:255
  for G = 1:255
    for B = 1:255
      if (size(cmap) ./ [1,3] == size(x))
        break;
      endif
      cmap=[cmap;R/255,G/255,B/255];

    endfor
    if (size(cmap) ./ [1,3] == size(x))
        break;
    endif
  endfor 
 if (size(cmap) ./ [1,3] == size(x))
        break;
 endif 
endfor

colormap(cmap);

scatter(x,y,20, 1:100);
```

Comment: Can you give a code example ?
Let's say that my x and y vectors are:
x = randn (100, 1);
y = randn (100, 1);

Comment: I have changed it...it took me 2 hours to study Octave and Octave's scattler to done it...

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how do I designate particular colors to each vector? Using this code I am restricted to just black and blue.

Comment: You shall get all possible colors, if you have 255^3 vectors...if you want less colors and more differents between them, change all 255 to smaller number :)

Comment: Because I have misunderstood some things in the scatter function, my question as it was stated till now did not worth. Therefore I have changed it in order to reflect your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a nice illustrative example:

```
X = linspace(0, 4 * pi, 100);                       % Create points (100 elements)
Y = 100 * sin(X); 

S = Y + 100;                                        % Sizes array. All values need 
                                                    % to be larger than 0

C = [linspace(0,1,100); ones(1,100); ones(1,100)]'; % create hsv triplets at full 
                                                    % saturation and value that
                                                    % cover the whole colour 
                                                    % (i.e. hues) spectrum

C = hsv2rgb(C);                                     % convert to rgb triplets; to
                                                    % be used as a 'colour array'

scatter(X,Y,S,C,'filled','MarkerEdgeColor','k');    % fill bubbles, black border
```

[image]

Comment: Because I have misunderstood some things in the scatter function, my question as it was stated till now did not worth. Therefore I have changed it in order to reflect your answer.

Comment: Glad you found it useful :)