# Changing color of plot lines in a loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, colors

I have a question about changing the color of lines in a plot in MATLAB. I have written a code where I want to change the color of lines in a plot that is embedded in several for loops (the code is shown below). In the code, a new plot is created (with its own figure) when the "if loop" condition is satisfied. I want each plot to have lines with different colors (from other plots), so I created a variable = "NewColor" to increment and change the line colors. However, the following problem has been occurring:

Suppose I am in debug mode and I have stopped at the plot command. I run the next step and a plot is created with a blue line. I check the value of NewColor and find NewColor = 0.1. Next, I use the "run to cursor" command to step to the next time the plot command is activated. When I do this I am still within the "i for loop", so NewColor has not changed. I check the editor to find that NewColor = 0.1. Therefore, when I run the next step a blue line should show up on the current plot. To the contrary and my disbelief an orange line shows up (in addition to the blue line). I don't understand since in both steps of the debugger NewColor = 0.1, and the code is written so the color of the lines = [0,NewColor,0]. If anyone can find the error of my ways it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
ThetaPlot = [40,50];   % Put incident angle as input

Count1 = 0;
Count2 = 0;
NewColor = 0;

for m = 1:length(ThetaPlot)
    NewColor = 0.1;
    Title = sprintf('Angle(%d)',ThetaPlot(m));
    figure('name',Title)
    Count1 = 0;
    for i = 1:length(xrange)-1             % X Coordinate of Start Node
        for j = 1:length(yrange)-1         % Y Coordinate of Start Node
            Count1 = Count1+1;
            for k = 2:length(xrange)       % X Coordinate of End Node
                for l = 2:length(yrange)   % Y Coordinate of End Node
                    Count2 = Count2+1;
                    if ReflRayData(Count2,ThetaPlot(m) - ThetaIncident(1) + 1,Count1) == 1
                        x = [xrange(i),xrange(k)];
                        y = [yrange(j),yrange(l)];
                        plot(x,y,['-',[0,NewColor,0],'o']);
                        hold on;
                    end
                end
                Count2 = 0;
            end
        end
    end
    NewColor = NewColor + 0.02;
end
```

Full Code:

```
%% Calculating Angles of Reflection

run = 1; % Set run = 1 for calculations

if run == 1
    xrange = [0:1:14.5]';      % Coordinates to try for Panel Geometry (in)
    yrange = [0:1:36]';        % Coordinates to try for Panel Geometry (in)
    ThetaIncident = [-90:1:90]';     % Incident Angle of Ray (measured relative to normal direction with clockwise postive)
    OvenGlassXrange = [14.5:0.1:36.5]; %Range of X coordinates for Oven Glass

ReflRayData = zeros((length(xrange)-1)*(length(yrange)-1),length(ThetaIncident),(length(xrange)-1)*(length(yrange)-1));  % Matrix containing Reflected Ray Data

Count1 = 0;
Count2 = 0;
for i = 1:length(xrange)-1             % X Coordinate of Start Node
    for j = 1:length(yrange)-1         % Y Coordinate of Start Node
        Count1 = Count1+1;
        for k = 2:length(xrange)       % X Coordinate of End Node
            for l = 2:length(yrange)   % Y Coordinate of End Node
                Count2 = Count2+1;
                for m = 1:length(ThetaIncident)
                    xStart = xrange(i);
                    yStart = yrange(j);
                    xEnd = xrange(k);
                    yEnd = yrange(l);

                    m1 = (yEnd - yStart)/(xEnd - xStart);  % Slope between Start and End Nodes
                    b1 = yStart - m1*xStart;

                    m2 = 1/m1;                             % Slope of normal direction

                    b2 = (yEnd - 0.5*(yEnd - yStart)) - m2*(xEnd - 0.5*(xEnd - xStart));

                    ArbXCoor = 1;                          % Arbitary Point X Coordinate on Normal Line
                    ArbYCoor = m2*ArbXCoor+b2;             % Arbitary Point Y Coordinate on Normal Line

                    ThetaReflected = -ThetaIncident(m);       % Reflected Angle

                    ArbXCoorRot = ArbXCoor*cosd(ThetaReflected) - ArbYCoor*sind(ThetaReflected); % Arbitary Point X Coordinate on Reflected Line
                    ArbYCoorRot = ArbYCoor*cosd(ThetaReflected) + ArbXCoor*sind(ThetaReflected); % Arbitary Point Y Coordinate on Reflected Line

                    m3 = (ArbYCoorRot - (yEnd - 0.5*(yEnd - yStart)))/(ArbXCoorRot - (xEnd - 0.5*(xEnd - xStart))); % Slope of Reflected Line
                    b3 = (yEnd - 0.5*(yEnd - yStart)) - m3*(xEnd - 0.5*(xEnd - xStart));

                    ElemLength = sqrt((yEnd - yStart)^2 + (xEnd - xStart)^2);

                    if min(OvenGlassXrange) < -b3/m3 && -b3/m3 < max(OvenGlassXrange) && -1 < m1 && m1 < 0 && m1 ~= -Inf && m1 ~= Inf && ElemLength < 3
                        ReflRayData(Count2,m,Count1) = 1;
                    end 
                end
            end
        end
        Count2 = 0;
    end
end

%% Plotting

ThetaPlot = [40,50];   % Put incident angle as input

Count1 = 0;
Count2 = 0;
NewColor = 0;

for m = 1:length(ThetaPlot)
    NewColor = 0.1;
    Title = sprintf('Angle(%d)',ThetaPlot(m));
    figure('name',Title)
    Count1 = 0;
    for i = 1:length(xrange)-1             % X Coordinate of Start Node
        for j = 1:length(yrange)-1         % Y Coordinate of Start Node
            Count1 = Count1+1;
            for k = 2:length(xrange)       % X Coordinate of End Node
                hold on;
                for l = 2:length(yrange)   % Y Coordinate of End Node
                    Count2 = Count2+1;
                    if ReflRayData(Count2,ThetaPlot(m) - ThetaIncident(1) + 1,Count1) == 1
                        x = [xrange(i),xrange(k)];
                        y = [yrange(j),yrange(l)];
                        plot(x,y,['-',[0,NewColor,0],'o']);
                        hold on;
                    end
                end
                Count2 = 0;
            end
        end
    end
    NewColor = NewColor + 0.02;
end
```

Comment: Many of your variables are undefined. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please try to put 'figure;hold on;' before your 'for' loop and remove that 'hold on' in your loop. If it works, I will write you a complete answer

Comment: Please explain your `plot` call. `['-',[0,NewColor,0],'o']` makes no sense as an argument to `plot`.

Comment: The idea of [0,NewColor,0] is that colors can be defined in matlab by their rgb values in the format [r,g,b]. For example, [1,1,0] is yellow.

Comment: Also, from past experience the only way I know to define an rgb color, specify the line type, and specify the marker type is to use the format I have in the code.

Comment: `['-',[0,NewColor,0],'o']` tries to concatenate `'-'`, `[0, NewColor, 0]`, and `'o'` together into a string. Remove the outer `[]`.

Comment: that still won't work @excaza, it's still not a correct call to `plot` without specifying what properties those things refer to. @Grady I've given you the correct format in an answer below. (I haven't looked at the rest of the code for bugs mind you, just this plot line.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `plot(x,y,['-',[0,NewColor,0],'o']);` try:

```
plot(x,y,'linestyle','-','marker','o','color',[0,NewColor,0])
```

Comment: Also, might I suggest using hsv2rgb with an ascending argument as a very nice way of changing 'hue' rather than a single r,g or b channel's intensity. I answered a question recently where I give such an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38550379/how-to-use-different-color-for-each-vector-in-scatter-function-gnu-octave/38557802#38557802 ... I think your colour change will stand out much better :)

Answer (score -1):

According to the Matlab documentation, by calling `hold on` Matlab uses the next color.

> hold on retains plots in the current axes so that new plots added to the axes do not delete existing plots. New plots use the next colors and line styles based on the ColorOrder and LineStyleOrder properties of the axes.

Therefore, in your code when you call `hold on` inside the `for`, it just uses the next color.

My solution is to put `figure; hold on;` before `for` loop and remove that one in you loop

Comment: He is attempting to pass colors explicitly with each `plot` call. `hold`'s affect on the axes' next color is not relevant. Besides, calling `hold on` repeatedly vs. calling it once makes no difference to the behavior.