# Matlab generate a heatmap on sphere

Tags: matlab

I have points that are all part of a spherical surface. How can I create a 3D sphere where the color of the sphere is determined by the density of the points (smoothed). An example of data points can be found in the picture below.
[image: sphere]

Using the following code, the points can be colored:

```
x = data(:,1);
y = data(:,2);
z = data(:,3);
D = [x(:), y(:), z(:)];
N = numel(x);

%// calculation of color vector
[n,m] = ndgrid(1:N,1:N);
%// euclidian distance of each point to every other point
X = arrayfun(@(a,b) sum( (D(a,:) - D(b,:)).^2 ), n, m);

%// threshold factor
T = 1;

%// sort distances of points
Y = sort(X,2);
%// calculate average distance of the closest T% of all points
Z = mean(Y(:,2:ceil(N*T)),2);

%// plot
colormap jet;
scatter3(x,y,z,20,-Z,'filled');
title('T = 0.01')
```

[image: colored]
Now, I want to color a sphere according to the data. The following figure is for random data.

```
[x,y,z] = sphere;
surf(x,y,z,rand(length(x)));
colormap jet
shading interp
```

[image: randomsphere]

Sample of my data:

```
-0.636016480755703  0.617525876796302   -0.0928047432418846
-0.973951523685005  1.33968621140501    -0.484260283616615
-1.09449677739217   1.95314823996034    -0.997620228061477
-1.27650273224044   2.30054644808743    -1.52076502732240
-1.34107124912069   2.50643151442066    -1.93523263993568
-1.41743718592965   2.64326633165829    -2.38693467336683
-1.52722674072605   2.66172386431264    -2.68924816504662
-1.78737177571955   2.53918932377253    -2.86176675629917
-2.13798636181308   2.25411151223426    -2.71760930605696
-2.63246062794664   1.72971210753335    -2.72474671481593
-3.03187531422826   1.12946204122675    -3.07732528909000
-3.24477552244776   0.394710528947106   -3.67518248175182
2.78947368421053    1.11300309597523    -4.46904024767802
2.49650108417110    1.17716341415336    -4.93987778434851
2.52268839923534    0.940134822416742   -5.07883086829661
2.87130058385343    0.507398832293135   -4.76887457217636
3.04415584415584    0.461038961038961   -4.41298701298701
3.09087249672940    0.653567475093087   -4.11894938110094
3.11987397479496    0.702540508101620   -3.94573914782957
3.17966101694915    0.719840478564307   -3.52233300099701
3.12836149155253    0.840997700689793   -2.86519044286714
2.97330943133154    0.892490787770142   -2.26048202370282
2.81690697215090    0.873000197511357   -1.86114951609718
2.72014039944631    0.816195372750643   -1.64094324698438
2.50647023691021    0.872387019709337   -1.35715707744376
2.23888664376642    0.836886239644373   -1.02939987876339
1.96850235730765    0.814575183067509   -0.776808105125891
1.64841095342794    1.11333200079952    -0.690885468718768
1.36944528036914    1.18331828668874    -0.567609589728157
0.920234429323533   0.813251216847125   -0.225489222211184
0.570574643359454   0.388738195700221   -0.0264215390797675
0.316863696069516   -0.0561281196322118 0.0646660604223506
0.338646811912852   -0.391515090945433  0.0651609034579250
0.479434319290907   -0.676526242406135  0.0231052683995618
0.505991285403050   -0.746187363834423  0.00925925925925952
0.399658325796402   -0.813636820420058  0.0130640136669684
0.182226660009985   -0.957613579630554  0.00439340988517190
-0.0248032672576950 -1.24863034166750   -0.0676860245044320
-0.283441074092491  -1.72710094480358   -0.272948781700647
-0.527511004401761  -2.34133653461385   -0.705782312925170
-0.797852242219350  -2.97176096251367   -1.49487918862484
-0.922330097087379  -3.29166249624662   -2.23876488839956
-0.898067487734055  -3.46104936417343   -3.16261139481326
-0.727430211839240  -3.46159176400713   -3.78058800237577
-0.614893829129698  -3.34522978765826   -4.33002691655867
-0.453940686573228  -3.06104001625025   -4.98694901482836
-0.173647905628312  -2.72118364490653   -5.48340497850645
0.0242345666699911  -2.38655629799541   -5.81115986835544
0.198836859520706   -2.10383034192319   -6.01564223403189
0.380042037834051   -1.79871884696227   -6.17951156040436
0.423617429986857   -1.63856030735012   -6.25290668284299
0.368721000605205   -1.66920516441396   -6.24581400040347
0.0171154038634771  -1.99409468521670   -6.09303373035732
-0.396368687369779  -2.45550153785098   -5.72055759499951
-0.911024174942322  -3.02593038419099   -4.85911325107834
-1.22442557442557   -3.29275724275724   -3.85614385614386
-1.22364472894579   -3.30446089217844   -2.70414082816563
-1.09318766066838   -3.01586909234724   -1.74006327862369
-0.846371252649642  -2.61244574543252   -1.05284142525487
-0.594202898550724  -2.24637681159420   -0.644927536231885
-0.493466023321271  -2.07438681141938   -0.501708886208283
-0.414079822616408  -1.88802660753880   -0.374168514412417
-0.0486402719456110 -1.25204959008198   -0.0690361927614474
0.514052222443692   -0.238489136934423  0.0455451465018948
1.25832163625426    0.215410066172047   -0.196310407058352
1.72030784508441    0.633813306852036   -0.532571996027806
2.33757173956066    1.28933306946368    -1.43583019988126
2.66762105686156    1.66294956801286    -2.65888085191883
2.82720953326713    1.42879841112215    -3.80993048659384
2.70761349939735    1.02732020891924    -4.72047006830052
2.42173094081491    0.500297412511153   -5.41731932189947
1.64370927318296    -0.734636591478697  -6.11152882205514
1.19525675811476    -1.17174153351422   -6.22434931162697
1.11648548917922    -1.26179315847213   -6.22569063528473
1.11648548917922    -1.26179315847213   -6.22569063528473
1.29463307776561    -1.04600219058050   -6.21905805038335
1.69427680547174    -0.494216455441561  -6.11265338966003
2.19971642697995    0.369252582540004   -5.67956248734049
2.63406087304766    1.03103724469363    -4.84551461754105
2.90801393728223    1.36689895470383    -3.48257839721254
2.69187842551071    1.30109616342800    -2.03637269556552
2.04063692987744    0.843078159533856   -0.848754269640346
1.28362077559565    0.0458578406938491  -0.185724254810089
0.722807017543860   -0.518245614035088  -0.00491228070175431
0.548188515490968   -0.832172772227268  -0.0118579069532743
0.489908530522967   -1.08401272618811   -0.0579140982302633
0.485282298573438   -1.30887080570625   -0.124573035965441
0.674118231495281   -1.33253849975161   -0.168007948335817
0.910319782104308   -1.33229093110057   -0.229244426510643
1.52194752774975    -1.40302724520686   -0.515186680121089
1.94507084414289    -1.55647575334265   -0.876222310915985
2.35918818446699    -1.89234401687933   -1.55827388727017
2.71365858525392    -2.06993913997805   -2.58001596328445
2.86434225027552    -1.95721871555956   -3.17287846909127
2.85724240915879    -1.92110502737680   -3.66057740169238
2.87056949422541    -1.78156113102350   -3.98426921545201
2.87284396309667    -1.61111111111111   -4.25952667468913
2.80383257690368    -1.63519919314170   -4.40963187090267
2.74593029062219    -1.74528113452512   -4.41146509537601
2.79961927662559    -1.78649433924456   -4.21245366195772
2.90093495126318    -1.80893176845037   -3.77849612094689
2.92225456735595    -1.85735796024895   -3.29276249749046
2.79813695871098    -1.99234642497482   -2.74043303121853
2.69918862065511    -1.87313432835821   -2.15235901031754
2.52209558088382    -1.58498300339932   -1.52319536092781
2.00474364150182    -1.47204279370206   -0.880904319741623
1.51878192927978    -1.62576379845738   -0.618351197034960
1.23150095123661    -1.63627716030840   -0.477520777010114
0.531772406847935   -1.78439073514602   -0.336606243705942
0.0184244597151679  -1.70859476147794   -0.250473060452145
-0.761328398519556  -1.39836951085326   -0.212463739121736
-1.14685385314615   -1.00161599838400   -0.209473790526209
-1.46421063169486   -0.401441585744319  -0.256982680949045
-1.65316831683168   0.183663366336634   -0.385742574257425
-1.74656382873529   0.675961633540987   -0.563532087412242
-1.89565826330532   0.973389355742297   -0.793417366946779
-2.13232939763858   1.09455673404042    -1.06588953372023
-2.22335431025872   1.24398162021776    -1.26261112775946
-2.25349301397206   1.26686626746507    -1.31457085828343
-2.32195949316572   1.27616482091190    -1.40491868701985
-2.32195949316572   1.27616482091190    -1.40491868701985
-2.25349301397206   1.26686626746507    -1.31457085828343
-1.94300518134715   1.07393383818254    -0.884216819449980
-1.58513309894525   0.672978402812657   -0.464239075841286
-1.23895482198065   0.186895382467338   -0.184202652837339
-0.579979879275654  -0.312776659959758  0.0340040241448691
0.0370258577321662  -0.908441493107959  0.0195693731763762
0.0376980148385803  -1.41537998796872   -0.125025065169440
-0.218357293656379  -1.75379511410476   -0.280838443751885
-0.596396934408281  -2.03976311336717   -0.499353040708669
-0.921337706221428  -2.33015305108328   -0.810922281852514
-1.15569341604963   -2.61947168300981   -1.20672403442065
-1.34566968781470   -2.98257804632427   -1.89088620342397
-1.47722515698196   -3.13345958337486   -2.45724110435563
-1.56538309245694   -3.18704216986735   -3.03009305088101
-1.66732830488289   -3.12643906312029   -3.51667328304883
-1.69259886442873   -3.09971112660624   -3.62316963841020
-1.71797696544817   -3.10520781171758   -3.39609414121182
-1.73907022749753   -3.08506429277943   -2.99891196834817
-1.55176565008026   -3.07383627608347   -2.38804173354735
-1.29407651583258   -2.96668664469084   -1.81125761662172
-1.06947201270345   -2.71119491861850   -1.26915442635967
-0.663021769522668  -2.13655881765528   -0.580487317755142
-0.209927507047926  -1.41683447442610   -0.132400322190898
0.163531402408679   -0.794366477555489  0.0366278491091858
0.418277331747448   -0.462037863019130  0.0522846664684309
0.586739327883742   -0.290644868301544  0.0331516802906444
0.652918908149034   -0.108686989440127  0.0178322374975086
0.687443901466042   0.142016555300688   -0.00982347661314398
0.774385999801134   0.549766331908124   -0.105846673958437
0.841714797849034   0.982473610834495   -0.267128062139017
0.827499243417734   1.33965499848684    -0.436951477857360
0.812180194642320   1.71977525835256    -0.683806561653456
0.701562344511892   1.92168374962683    -0.817593790426909
0.435846429281878   2.00925004973145    -0.835289437039984
0.0682452642073778  2.07342971086740    -0.857926221335992
-0.307490144546649  2.10891539472354    -0.912059031638532
-0.719540461553966  2.05698881386677    -0.951073264133830
-1.10075818036712   2.00598563447726    -1.05367118914605
-1.56707560343108   1.90325154598045    -1.24182126471175
-1.69690374913443   1.87555643486003    -1.31931941834009
-1.91472868217054   1.74031007751938    -1.37984496124031
-2.14285714285714   1.58571428571429    -1.47142857142857
-2.36444466520962   1.38793959864892    -1.56134512219352
-2.58613043040016   0.984326176796694   -1.54314081241810
-2.78857029467209   0.479015775374541   -1.57148526639548
-2.87015945330296   -0.105922551252847  -1.55694760820046
-2.83612343686971   -1.03781766841468   -1.68132311415894
-2.71839481555334   -1.49127617148554   -1.76859421734796
-2.48778316351766   -1.82011079236324   -1.67815807696112
-2.17667773417849   -2.01398531039340   -1.44018512928866
-1.81555333998006   -2.16919242273180   -1.21395812562313
-1.31528822055138   -2.21709273182957   -0.899348370927319
-0.798962386511025  -2.21465629053178   -0.675745784695200
-0.261611611611612  -2.25895895895896   -0.600350350350350
0.208694338101954   -2.17585129961717   -0.534757203304453
0.449437082793664   -1.88831324100827   -0.379645312344326
1.00702458605118    -1.46929252383342   -0.313296537882589
1.28716658278812    -1.08983392048314   -0.289783593356819
1.57556687643592    -0.714613924682849  -0.347118170012986
1.68775020016013    -0.484787830264211  -0.382706164931946
1.61437908496732    -0.599346405228758  -0.352287581699347
1.57417582417582    -0.575274725274726  -0.327472527472528
1.78015328761597    -0.188987494957644  -0.430012101653893
2.06253743262128    0.340786584148532   -0.696196845677780
2.25189017111023    0.728014325507362   -0.992240350179069
2.30490383647165    0.963548484543349   -1.16680092639211
2.16848971399900    1.16432513798294    -1.14706472654290
1.52051204515674    1.44758592883782    -0.814585223263785
0.938315894369706   1.52640757349278    -0.587493771798705
0.270871327254306   1.42152988855117    -0.376393110435664
-0.431318681318681  1.27967032967033    -0.317582417582417
-1.24290141971606   1.11672665466907    -0.472905418916217
-1.67691236446832   0.878344772704665   -0.596737292350543
-2.09241823587711   0.562239841427156   -0.782804757185331
-2.46963156309608   0.160676638891678   -1.04607971087240
-2.80539575481055   -0.297758381273557  -1.44653838524102
-3.04411764705882   -0.720588235294118  -1.97058823529412
-3.10657776893223   -0.932530600059707  -2.24584535774704
-3.10657776893223   -0.932530600059707  -2.24584535774704
-3.09186140209508   -0.923851732473811  -2.19580983078163
-3.06973971786211   -0.972282932644546  -2.16371945161931
-2.97409275190349   -1.18797587263918   -2.06679521408089
-2.58697813121272   -1.65029821073559   -1.67783300198807
-2.17490305260018   -1.82484836432336   -1.27145271949886
-1.54121682978509   -1.85420240137221   -0.764806780345071
-0.516422082459818  -1.59888190076869   -0.243535988819008
0.621063189568706   -1.10441323971916   -0.0862587763289868
1.66834120365719    -0.593388927961419  -0.382296794936200
2.25558547775783    -0.621284659884301  -0.821115100738080
2.66296629662966    -0.781178117811781  -1.31313131313131
2.87842586085734    -1.01686577652846   -1.74947294448349
2.96028014007004    -1.22826413206603   -2.06478239119560
2.91112000800721    -1.21779601641477   -1.94089680712641
2.57236973447794    -0.810141744859253  -1.20203633459772
1.39727199516811    -0.142490436883430  -0.223273605798269
-0.231495280675608  -0.227620466964729  0.0772975658221564
-1.18559766176174   -0.862426930054425  -0.193156621648861
-1.58402645555667   -1.20913919230384   -0.475849283495340
-1.75749674054759   -1.35924180122355   -0.641209507571959
-1.79383084577114   -1.39004975124378   -0.679502487562189
-1.71299871299871   -1.39956439956440   -0.629096129096129
-1.11655827913957   -1.16223111555778   -0.242321160580290
-0.445971516781197  -0.933323374165920  -0.0159346678617660
0.420428269830099   -0.767165979692369  0.0181461747260472
1.62276740919125    -0.599237407184427  -0.356963676500100
2.24262721183645    -0.868489453164051  -0.859792062381285
2.62592815572948    -1.10194661850291   -1.37818583182822
2.92154718106791    -1.41344337277518   -2.13826190712936
3.03345724907063    -1.55018587360595   -2.76765799256506
3.09189297524802    -1.50085178875639   -3.27382503256839
3.09373122371320    -1.44131784498298   -3.61686360905267
3.12990756386045    -1.36810456217076   -3.53021568432561
3.24122807017544    -1.02192982456140   -3.09649122807018
3.16491701659668    -0.546140771845631  -2.23975204959008
2.47121620273371    -0.127007881871695  -1.01326948019555
1.11460425873845    -0.123443149859381  -0.108879067898755
-0.332014246141670  -0.423624851602691  0.0643055005935889
-1.35305494941480   -1.01175362031343   -0.298055941281492
-1.85162601626016   -1.81846123339282   -0.961679555819949
-2.02630258006224   -1.98925810661580   -1.25148077502259
-2.06198595787362   -1.93941825476429   -1.24523570712136
-2.02630258006224   -1.98925810661580   -1.25148077502259
-1.88748763600396   -1.92814045499505   -1.07141444114738
-0.928151469855506  -1.61086198305929   -0.349725959142999
-0.0390547263681593 -0.873084577114428  0.0264676616915427
0.855323383084577   -0.356019900497513  -0.0278606965174126
1.91169066559259    -0.262007854193938  -0.516816030611217
2.74024280124411    -0.390037122504264  -1.35356677034213
3.18088116410671    -0.598625707356508  -2.30901374292644
3.27699018538713    -0.869138495092693  -3.19520174482007
3.20708582834331    -1.02165668662675   -3.74411177644711
3.14159113796576    -1.02769385699899   -4.05659617321249
3.13289695527125    -1.02211643360111   -4.09486264008728
3.23694438907714    -0.827287223440303  -3.81029499701017
3.32393239323932    -0.460796079607961  -3.07100710071007
2.90476664344711    -0.0317444521842970 -1.62528609811922
1.52950526524935    -0.148023047883966  -0.287701172263063
0.185110663983903   -0.638430583501006  0.0575452716297797
-1.09335745151241   -1.15500954677922   -0.231635011556627
-1.58385217915244   -1.54348262703354   -0.614982928298855
-1.71489128266507   -1.62602234191103   -0.741871135048873
-1.71489128266507   -1.62602234191103   -0.741871135048873
-1.65856458374925   -1.63770213615492   -0.710620882411659
-1.41790441547944   -1.54981307466909   -0.525108618773366
-1.29696668324217   -1.44157135753357   -0.417503729487817
-1.12397315167301   -1.18648567421358   -0.252554598276898
-0.854046242774566  -1.05780346820809   -0.128612716763007
-0.666666666666667  -1.33333333333333   -0.166666666666667
-0.521618405394685  -1.73125743752479   -0.307417691392304
-0.0915189746670674 -2.03509562431161   -0.433964153399419
1.20271210013908    -1.81606397774687   -0.561891515994436
1.86270346779901    -1.85527246992215   -0.996461429582448
1.86263846928499    -1.97301107754280   -1.08509566968782
1.76366703045937    -2.14922115289215   -1.15061017958131
1.76361819090455    -2.18985507246377   -1.18805597201399
1.68721529015647    -2.17250940780353   -1.10937809467221
1.65447768711595    -2.04371914979349   -0.976176085423593
1.60033760301857    -1.90715916989375   -0.838000198590011
1.44555845197514    -1.94866653298576   -0.770102265891318
1.31015187849720    -2.06075139888090   -0.774180655475619
1.16209202515221    -2.18400039924144   -0.793542269687593
1.04569463823002    -2.24302371935420   -0.788419374127964
0.958153103309526   -2.11618549441706   -0.656875565838447
0.961211161686127   -2.03423708687908   -0.600930140510587
1.00920920920921    -1.94034034034034   -0.557557557557558
1.01808382027000    -1.80727382631473   -0.481714688696353
0.951635560907084   -1.49859522376079   -0.307144290587999
0.803406952560166   -1.35560067346737   -0.207437852827573
0.785593473286240   -1.22505223360860   -0.158541438662819
0.580485838121157   -1.15290797298659   -0.0920270134059069
0.264785894206549   -1.10916876574307   -0.0380352644836268
-0.0502447307961242 -1.05444011587254   -0.0134352212566178
-0.339005104594135  -0.957711940746672  -0.00820738664798304
-0.516057585825028  -0.699889258028793  0.0143964562569212
-0.282254028625763  -0.610899809828846  0.0537984185767195
-0.313627353815659  -0.525173439048563  0.0592170465807742
-0.180463242698892  -0.550251762336354  0.0669687814702917
-0.0783649052841476 -0.817248255234297  0.0358923230309078
-0.0305602716468592 -0.871467092779387  0.0268650754019779
-0.0276997189883579 -0.866118024889603  0.0279004415897233
0.362864321608040   -0.759547738693467  0.0262311557788948
0.767242249823286   -0.540644249217409  -0.0170655356962532
0.732645497345487   -0.599569267755184  -0.0148752879895824
0.702180028129395   -0.490857946554149  0.00175808720112514
0.751281793505580   -0.310244294762240  -0.000854529003719851
0.798241206030151   -0.355075376884422  -0.0132160804020103
0.747126436781609   -0.454022988505747  -0.00574712643678188
0.489324726911619   -0.520953326713009  0.0381827209533263
0.258796481407437   -0.628248700519792  0.0537784886045589
0.217539977873881   -0.714723926380368  0.0457105501357740
0.0984422110552764  -0.856180904522613  0.0283919597989950
-0.154428614127727  -0.990734283152336  -0.00154428614127733
-0.298350228582787  -1.19866825680779   -0.0662890081494729
-0.546631864270656  -1.23100090352374   -0.109326372854132
-0.911847389558233  -1.03815261044177   -0.139959839357430
-1.06025781952633   -0.891775756970121  -0.153392625162387
-0.956119162640902  -0.889291465378422  -0.119162640901771
-0.957903780068729  -0.776632302405498  -0.0987972508591066
-0.983094928478544  -0.673201960588177  -0.0909772931879562
-0.917893375770838  -0.729809031231351  -0.0794708573702003
-0.916733911640105  -0.691194270728263  -0.0735323784547108
-0.849363437437836  -0.799035209866720  -0.0716132882434848
-0.744629833150165  -0.799330602457788  -0.0455090418623234
-0.598454636091725  -0.811714855433699  -0.0171485543369885
-0.481754002187531  -0.860495177488317  -0.00651287660336042
```

Comment: Coloring a sphere in Matlab is easy, but you'll first need to know which color to apply. You'll have to (1) split your sphere into `n` sectors, (2) count how many points `np` are in each sector, then (3) color each sector with a density of `d=n/np`. Try to have a go at (1) and (2), post your code attempts, detail what you are stuck with and people will be able to help you better (they are unlikely to write a full code for what you are asking).

Comment: similar : https://stackoverflow.com/q/44889914/5802041

Comment: Please put a link to the sample data, or supply a sample set than we can test with.

Comment: You said the points belong to a sphere. Do you have the properties of the sphere available (`Radius` and `Center coordinates`) ? It would make the solution a lot easier.

Comment: Not directly related, but take a look on [`pdist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html?s_tid=doc_ta) for calculating the distances instead of using `arrayfun`.

Comment: [x y z] = sphere;
surf(x, y+0.5, z+1)
This generates a sphere on the points.